# How can i make a single Admin account for my AWS Amplify Blog

Tags: authentication, authorization, admin, aws-amplify

I am making an **AWS Amplify blog** application for a customer/friend , it is a blog where he will be able to upload images and create posts.

How can I create an **Admin account** for him? Keep in mind **he will be the only person with an account**, **users will NOT be able to make an account**.

As such I thought of just making an account for him and having no signup functionality in my website but I don't know how to do that.

The other option would be some kind of admin group role for his account so that if malicious users find a way to signup ( if it is even possible ) they won't be able to do anything

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/)?

Comment: yes, however that is used ( im pretty sure ) for managing other users. What I want , is one singular admin user and no more users

Comment: Why not just add him to the cognito user pool and give no front-end functionality sign up? Then make all the graphql queries for mutations owner, and give IAM permissions for public users to read the blogss

Comment: - no front-end functionality sign up -, thats what i thought of doing, was just wondering if a user can somehow get access to the library from the console and try make an account. Pretty silly question maybe but i honestly don't know ... it is just really unclear to me what a user can do client-side and what he can't do on a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is one possible solution:**

1. Register the Admin via the Cognito Console
2. Have a hidden sign-in page for the Admin that isn't accessible via the UI
3. Do not offer sign-up functionality on the website.
4. Ensure writes are allowed by the owner, and reads by public with IAM. [More information here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/auth/#dynamic-group-authorization).

**Sign Up is used via `Auth.signUp` like below:**

*This can just not be setup and thus will prevent users from registering.*

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signUp() {
    try {
        const { user } = await Auth.signUp({
            username,
            password,
        });
        console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
}
```

If you offer a custom sign-in solution, as opposed to [withAuthenticator](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator), create account can be mitigated.